# does my degreaser hang around and destroy my new chain lube?

Tags: maintenance, chain, lubricant

I generally clip on the Park chain cleaner, fill it with a cheap department store degreaser (Rubbermaid), run it through for a few seconds, then fill the chain cleaner with water once or twice or more to get rid of the degreaser.  I've been trying out Purple Extreme lube lately.  I'm not getting 100 miles out of an application of Purple Extreme (Conditions have been wet, but not "extreme") .  I'm convinced that some of the degreaser stays behind and breaks down the new lube.  Could this product contain detergents that stay behind and destroy the new lube?  Is this the difference between $10.00 per gallon department store degreaser and $50.00 per gallon "Bicycle" degreaser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible that degreaser is staying around and breaking down the lube. I use a citrus degreaser (green label but I don't remember the name), and I've never had issues scrubbing it off the chain or cassettes. Also make sure you use a rag to wipe the chain down before you apply the lube.

Comment: Do dry the chain after cleaning it - could be that water is stopping the lube getting into the chain joints

Comment: Depending on outside temperature I also use hot water for the final rinse, and wash out the chain cleaner before doing that. But I've not had this problem. If you're seeing any foaming when you wash the chain you still have degreaser and need to rinse some more.